# Vue: Use data to control DOM (but v-for, v-if, v-model, and v-show don't suffice)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, dom, vuejs2

I have used Vue before and I know how to use `v-for` to render a sequence of elements, `v-if` or `v-show` to show elements conditionally, and `v-model` to control, say, the contents of a paragraph.

But now I need some finer control over the DOM:

- I have a `ranges` object inside my component's `data` and there's a `text` div in my template (`text` may be an id and/or ref attribute).
- For every range, I want to highlight a certain part of text inside the `text` div based not on string or regex matching, but on text indexes (I previously did this with [Rangy](https://github.com/timdown/rangy)).
- I'd also like to insert some tooltip or popover such as [v-tooltip](https://akryum.github.io/v-tooltip) at each range [*optional*].

For example, I want to highlight *the* in `<div ref='text'>The cat chases a dog.</div>`inside when my ranges object contains `{ start: 0, end: 3 }`.

Manipulating the DOM does not work for me in this case because (i) there will be updates to `data` causing Vue to update the DOM again, deleting previous edits and (ii) elements subsequently inserted by something like `document.createElement('my-component');` are not even recognized as components by Vue.

Is there any way to do what I need utilizing Vue's data driven approach?

Comment: I have no experience creating text highlighting using Vue's native engine, but it is possible to re-execute non-Vue related algorithms under a certain lifecycle hook. Just run your highlighting method inside something like `updated()`, make sure to wrap it inside `this.$nextTick(func)`. Upon doing so, even if Vue replaces all your manual DOM updates whenever the component changes its state, you can re-apply your manual DOM updates.

Comment: Unless your component is frequently updating (maybe it's a component that updates on an interval) and your manual DOM update is very heavy, you shouldn't have problems in performance.

Answer (score 1):

sure, Vue does not working with appending DOM, 
try this. Works fine :

By splitting the text. we got an array of length 2

1. **first part** of array `l[0]` **:** is the text before highlighted text
2. **second part** of array `l[1]` **:** is the text after highlighted text

Then we merge : `l[0] + <p style="/* some style */"> + hightlighted_text + </p> + l[1]`

Then we bind HTML to div using `v-html`

> You need to make some validation like : if highlighted text **exists** in whole text. if not, this will cause ***adding new text to the whole text***.

```js
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        words: '',
        text: 'hello world im vue.js',
        hightlighted: ''
    },
    methods: {
        highlightMe() {
            var l = this.text.split(this.words);
            console.log(l);
            this.hightlighted = l[0] + '<p style="background-color: red; display: inline">' + this.words + '</p>' + l[1];
        }
    },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.2.4/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
<label>text to be highlighted :</label><br />
<input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="words"><br/>
<button @click="highlightMe">hightLight ` {{ words }} `</button>
<div>
  {{text}}
</div>
<div v-html="hightlighted"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I can't use most of your answer as the highlighting is done by Rangy, but it seems I can just let Rangy do it's work and then copy the modified element. In my case the element with `v-html` has an ID, let's also call it `highlighted`, and then I do `this.highlighted = document.getElementById('highlighted');`

Comment: But there's one problem: I'd really like to bind event handlers (`@click='doSomething'`) to the HTML. This doesn't work because the HTML inserted by `v-html` is not compiled... Is there a way to do so?

Comment: Create a component and then bind the highlighted text to that component. - like <new-comp :styled_text="highlighted" /> - Then you need to bind the first and second parts to Vue data - to use them inside #app with highlighted text. - then you can include your event inside new-comp. Sorry i cant write code now because im outside home and i use mobile.